# How to specify transitive dependency for bouncycastle in spring boot gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-security, bouncycastle

We are using Spring `org.springframework.boot" version '2.7.5'` where we identified some vulnerabilities with `bouncycastle` which has only transitive dependency in our project.

We wanted to specify the latest version of bouncycastle as it is described here [overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot)

```
ext['bouncycastle.version'] = '1.72'
```

Bust still after trying this, it shows the old dependency. Any idea what is missing ?

Dependency insight for `bouncycastle`

```
gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency bouncycastle --configuration compileClasspath
```

Result

```
org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.69
\--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:1.0.11.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.4
     |    \--- compileClasspath
     \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:3.1.4
          +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.4 (*)
          \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:3.1.4
               +--- compileClasspath (requested org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth)
               \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.4 (*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by using gradle constraints

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
 constraints {
        implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70'
        implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.70'
        implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15on:1.70'
 }
```

or by excluding it and adding the required dependencies manually

```
configurations.all {
   exclude group:"org.bouncycastle", module: "bcprov-jdk15on"
   exclude group:"org.bouncycastle", module: "bcutil-jdk15on"
   exclude group:"org.bouncycastle", module: "bcpkix-jdk15on"
}


implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.72'
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.72'
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:1.72'
```